# Alternative ways for handling keyboard dismissal when either child or parent view controller is tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a child view controller that has a UITextField. I also have a parent view controller in which I add a child view controller. The child view controller takes up about half of the parent view controller.

```
self.childVC = ChildViewController()
self.childVC.delegate = self 

func addChildViewController () {
self.addChildViewController(self.childVC)
self.childVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: widthOfContainerView, height: heightOfContainerView)
self.view.addSubview(self.childVC.view)
self.childVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

I'm having a keyboard presented when the user taps the UITextField, and I'd like the keyboard to be dismissed whenever the user taps outside the text field - which is either going to be within the child view controller's view, or the parent view controller's view.

Right now I'm redundantly setting up a tap gesture recognizer in **both** the child and parent view controllers to pull this off.

```
func setupTapGestureRecognizer() {
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

As a beginner, I suspect it's not great practice to have redundant code like this in my project, but I can't come up with any other ways to handle this.

What are some other ways I can ensure that tapping outside the textfield will dismiss the keyboard regardless of whether the user taps in the child view or parent view?

Thanks.

Comment: I think if you will only add the tap gesture on parent view controller and set userInteraction enable it will still work on tap on either view controllers view, only thing is your child view controller should not be having gesture that can take the action, means gesture are passed to parent if child can't handle it. I haven't tried it. Please let me know if this works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

5 years in and this is still one of the most annoying aspects of iOS that I have to deal with. Unfortunately I have not personally seen a drop-in approach that handles all the issues, but here's my approach FWIW:

First, instead of messing with `view.endEditing` or manually resigning first responder for the individual items, I tend to use the catch all:
`UIApplication.shared.sendAction(Selector(resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)`.

This easily takes care of general cases, as well as cases where the first responder (`TextField` in your example) may not be in the same View stack as the view being tapped. This also lends itself to being added as an `extension` in whatever way you prefer.

Aside from that it's really about maximizing coverage of your `tapGestures`. Here are some options I use:

- As @IraniyaNaynesh mentioned, fiddle with `userInteractionEnabled` to have taps fall through to the layer underneath where everything is handled.
- Make subclasses of `UIView`, `UILabel`, etc. that automatically handle taps to call `resignFirstResponder`.
- Dynamically add/remove a set of clear views while a `TextField` is editing. (Not ideal, but there are some circumstances were I've found this to be the simplest solution).

Hopefully someone out there (or Apple) can come up with a simpler solution for this!

Answer (score 0):

When you load a child view controller and add its view as a subview of the "parent" view controller, that view becomes part of the parent's view hierarchy.

Instead of adding Tab recognizers, you *could* simply use `touchesBegan()`.

In the "parent" VC, add this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

This will be triggered by a touch anywhere in the "child view" *or* in the "parent view". And, since the text field in the child view is *also* part of the view hierarchy, this will dismiss the keyboard.

This shows the relationship with an embedded VC (using Container View in Storyboard), but it will have the same behavior when loaded via code:

[image]

Touching anywhere in the blue "child view" or in the white "parent view" will trigger `touchesBegan` in the parent VC.